# Image Carousel not responding

Tags: html

I am having a problem where my image carousel is no longer working. It was working before an update to the website but I can't find the error. I was hoping a fresh set of eyes could help me figure out the problem.

```html
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel1" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"> <img src="Images/cara2.jpg" width="800" height="533" alt="First slide image" class="center-block">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>text</h3>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="Images/cara3.jpg" width="800" height="533" alt="Second slide image" class="center-block">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>text</h3>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="Images/cara1.jpg" width="800" height="533" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>text</h3>
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="Images/cara5.jpg" width="800" height="533" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="cara2">text</h3>
        <p class="cara2">text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img src="Images/archery (4).jpg" width="800" height="533" alt="Third slide image" class="center-block" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3 class="cara3">text</h3>
        <p class="cara3">text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am not sure what to put here, so here is the Code.

Comment: Its working fine at my end. Please share with me demo link. I think you missing main carousel file or bootstrap js file.

Comment: I will be honest, I am not sure what you mean. I will post the link www.cloverdaleconservationclub.com

Comment: Now, Please remove this css code in js file http://prntscr.com/ibpnx6